# Wildcard imports and PEP8 conundrum

Tags: python, pep8

I have a Django application and as a good practice, I have divided my setting file for different environments.

I have maintained a common settings file and then for each environment i.e. local, testing and production a setting file which imports all the variables from common. For this, it is imperative that I use `from common import *` which makes **PEP8** unhappy. Is there any way I can deal with this?

Comment: Maybe something like `import common as g` then qualify all those names with `g` ?

Comment: You are free to ignore PEP8 at your peril… But the point is very valid: *"Wildcard imports should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace"*. Why exactly is it "imperative" for you to do this?

Comment: a common setting file (for Django) has many setting parameters which I will need to import into my environment based setting files. This can also be achieved by writing each and every variable like from common import A, B, C, D ..... but a common setting file will have 100 such parameters (supposedly).

Comment: Remember, _PEP8 is only a guide_. Yes, it's the official Python code formatting guide, but it's still only a guide, not a hard and fast rule. Sometimes you may want to use a different style, and that's fine. The most important thing is being consistent. Note here I'm not saying you _should_ use wildcard `import`s - I still don't think you should - I'm simply saying be carful about how rigidly you follow PEP8.

Comment: Why not `import common`, then `common.A`…?

Comment: Within a package, for a module that has defined `__all__` properly, it's quite common and acceptable to use wildcard imports. E.g., `from .common import *`. This is, however, more used to import classes and functions into the main package namespace then to import constants.

Comment: Well, somewhere there was a solution - to make PEP8 happy adding #noqa at the end of such lines.